# How to get the length of a non list?

Tags: c#

Fixed it with:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> saveState = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>();
```

Don't mind this part:

I have some data I want to save to the player which I've done.

This data contains levels which the player needs to read which it can but when I'm creating UI elements for the levels I don't want to do a bunch of functions, I want to make it a lot easier so I can just call a function which iterates the levels and then creates a certain amount of frames depending on how many levels.

I want to count how many levels there are so I can "automate" this frame creation process and I need to get the levels data (if you've completed it and etc.)

Inside `PlayerData = new SetupData` I have a line which goes `Levels = new Levels` and inside that one I have two classes, objects whatever `Level1 = new Level`, and one `Level2 = new Level` I want to count how many of those there are with script.

If I were to add 5 more of the `Level2 = new Level` but level3, level4 etc. I want the computer to know how many of those there are inside of the `Levels = new Levels`

Basically:

```
Levels {

    Level1 = {Completed = true},
Level2 = {Completed = true},
Level3 = {Completed = true},

}
```

Count script:

```
Levels.Length // -- prints there are 3 levels.
```

This is just the players data:

```
public static SaveManager Instance { set; get; }
public SetupData state;

public object PlayerData;

PlayerData = new SetupData
    {
        // Level Data
        Levels = new Levels
        {
            Level1 = new Level
            {
                Name = "First Level",
                Progress = 0,
                Completed = false
            },
            Level2 = new Level
            {
                Name = "Second Level",
                Progress = 0,
                Completed = false
            },
        },
        // Character Data
        Player = new Player
        {
            SelectedColor = 0,
            Berries = 0
        }
    };
```

The problem is that this isn't a list or anything so I can't use `.Length`

SaveState script:

```
[Serializable]
public class Level
{
    public string Name;
    public int Progress;
    public bool Completed;
}

[Serializable]
public class Levels
{
    public Level Level1;
    public Level Level2;
}

[Serializable]
public class Player
{
    public int SelectedColor;
    public int Berries;
}

[Serializable]
public class SetupData
{
    public Levels Levels;
    public Player Player;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `Levels`? If it's an array or List to hold the levels you can easily get the Count or Length of it

Comment: “This isn't a list or anything”? Then you need to turn it into a list or something.

Comment: Is `Levels` actually a type? Or should that be `Levels = new List<Level>`?

Comment: I added the savestate script

Comment: Not sure what You are trying to count here , you are already presetting 2 levels per player, I see no list.
May be you wanna do a null check on one of the levels ? instead of counting

Comment: Ok based on your code so far you know there will always be two levels, because you only added properties for two levels. There's not to count, and you have no need  to count because you already know the answer even before you compile the code. As others mention, if you want to allow a varied number of levels, and then count them, you need a list to contain the Level objects instead of having a static property for each level.

Comment: I once again edited the question.

Comment: The question is still completely unclear I'm afraid. What are you trying to count?

Comment: Is your question "Given a type, how many fields of that type are of type `Level`?"

Comment: Why do you have `Level1`, `Level2` etc. properties, just have one property of type `List<Level>` where you can get a count instead of having to use reflection as per Eric's answer?

Comment: The fact that you're getting so much confusion from this question is because the operation you're describing, whatever it is, is not one that we normally do in C#. If your intention is that there can be a varying number of levels then, as David and others have indicated, normally you'd say `List<Level>` and not `Level1`, `Level2`, and so on.

Comment: I'll read about this List thing

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2, https://www.dotnetperls.com/list are good starting points. The nice thing about a List is you can make a list of any type. So in your case `public class SetupData
{
    public List<Level> Levels;
    public Player Player;
}` would be a sensible structure. And you can get rid of the `Levels` class entirely. Just keep `SetupData` and `Level` (and `Player` obviously, that's not relevant to this)

Comment: If you solved your own problem, put the answer in the Answer box below. Do not change your question. Also explain how the code solves your problem, because that is not at all clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to tell from this question what you are asking; please try to clarify the question.

My best guess is that you are asking "how can I programmatically count the number of fields of type `Levels` that are of type `Level`?"  If that's not your question, please clarify.

You do that like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Level { } 
class Levels 
{
    public Level level1;
    public Level level2;
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
          typeof(Levels)
            .GetFields()
            .Count(f => f.FieldType == typeof(Level)));
    }
}
```